# how to get removed perforce binary files in /opt/perforce directory

Tags: perforce

When I run `p4d` and `p4` I am getting `[p4: command not found]`

I have no binary files `p4d`, `p4` in */opt/perforce/* directory. So unable to run perforce server and client. I have tried with uninstalling perforce server and client. I am using ubuntu.

Finally, how can I get perforce binary files to run server and client

```
sudo apt-get install helix-p4d

removing existing dangling p4d link
/usr/sbin/p4d
linking /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d to /usr/sbin/p4d

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  Thank you for choosing Perforce Helix
::  The following has been installed by the 'helix-p4d' package:
::
::  - The Helix Version Engine (p4d)
::  - A 'perforce' system user
::  - p4dctl, a tool for managing Perforce service instances
::  - The Helix Command-Line Client (p4)
::
::  The Helix Version Engine is now installed, but not yet configured.
::  You must run the following to configure p4d (as root):
::
::    sudo /opt/perforce/sbin/configure-helix-p4d.sh
::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Started 0 services.
No services configured.


linking failed: linking /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d to /usr/sbin/p4d, because there is no p4d.
```

How to get all perforce binary files.

Answer (score 0):

Perforce requires at least two executables: the Perforce service (p4d on Unix, p4s.exe on Windows), and at least one Perforce application (such as p4 on UNIX, or p4.exe on Windows).

- [Helix Core (P4D) Server](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-core-p4d)
- [Helix Command-Line Client (P4)](https://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix-command-line-client-p4)

There is a lengthy list of prerequisites. Did you follow an installation procedure like this: "[p4search perforce application installation and configuration Guide in Linux](https://arkit.co.in/p4search-perforce-application-installation-linux/)".

You shouldn't get that message, instead you should see this:

```
apt-get install helix-p4d  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  helix-cli helix-cli-base helix-p4d-base helix-p4d-base-16.2 helix-p4dctl  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  helix-cli helix-cli-base helix-p4d helix-p4d-base helix-p4d-base-16.2 helix-p4dctl  
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 267 not upgraded.  
Need to get 6,722 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 15.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...

[Removed many lines]

...  
Setting up helix-p4d-base-16.2  
(2016.2-1468155~trusty) ...  
update-alternatives: using /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d.16.2 to provide /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d (helix-p4d) in auto mode  
Setting up helix-p4d-base (2016.2-1468155~trusty) ...  
Setting up helix-p4d (2016.2-1468155~trusty) ...  
linking /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d to /usr/sbin/p4d  

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
::  
::  Thank you for choosing Perforce Helix  
::  The following has been installed by the 'helix-p4d' package:  
::  
::  - The Helix Version Engine (p4d)  
::  - A 'perforce' system user  
::  - p4dctl, a tool for managing Perforce service instances  
::  - The Helix Command-Line Client (p4)  
::  
::  The Helix Version Engine is now installed, but not yet configured.  
::  You must run the following to configure p4d (as root):  
::  
::    sudo /opt/perforce/sbin/configure-helix-p4d.sh  
:: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  
Started 0 services.  
No services configured.  
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu10)  
...  
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19)  
...
```

Read the documentation for installation at: "[Installing and Upgrading the Server](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.install.html)".

> "The package update commands with apt-get or yum do not complete the process of updating your Perforce service. Packages for Linux simplify only certain steps of that process.
>
> Updating packages without completing the rest of the update process leaves your Perforce service in a precarious state. Make sure to read and understand the entire process before updating any packages.".

You need to:

1. Configure the Perforce package repository.
2. Import the Perforce package signing key.
3. Install the appropriate Perforce service package.
4. Run the post-installation configuration script.

See the link above ("[Installing and Upgrading the Server](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.install.html)") for complete details.